# Messages are not displaying after clicking command button in primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I used an input text, upload file and command button properties.My File upload mode is basic.In command button i made ajax=false.I used required=true in both the fields.While clicking save with empty fields, corresponding method is executing and message is displaying in console, but error message is not displaying in UI.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="addDialogWidgetVar" id="addDialogWidgetVarId"  dynamic="true" >

                <table  style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p:messages for="errorMsgId" id="errorMsgId" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" closable="true"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                <h:form id="formId" enctype="multipart/form-data">



                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label style="margin-top: 5%"><h:outputText value="Name:"/><h:outputText value="*" style="color:red"/></label>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%"/>
                            <td>
                                <p:inputText value="#{manageBean.attachment.fileName}" id="fileNameId" maxlength="60" style="width:70"
                                            required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}" requiredMessage="Please enter Attachment name"></p:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="10"></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label style="margin-top: 5%"><h:outputText value="Upload Attachment:"/><h:outputText value="*" style="color:red"/></label>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%"/>
                            <td>
                                <p:fileUpload label="Select a file" mode="simple" value="#{manageBean.attachment.file}"
                                            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/"
                                            invalidFileMessage="Allow only (pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG) file."
                                            multiple="false" required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}" requiredMessage="Please select a file" >
                                </p:fileUpload>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br />
                        <table style="margin-left: 30%;">                           
                        <tr align="center">

                            <td>
                                <p:commandButton value="Close" actionListener="#{manageBean.cancelAttachment}" oncomplete="addDialogWidgetVar.hide()" />
                            </td>

                            <td> 
                                <p:commandButton id="submitbtnid" value="Save" ajax="false" binding="#{save}"
                                            actionListener="#{manageBean.saveAttachment}" update=":errorMsgId"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </h:form>

            </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try do submit without ajax for test, and also put p:growl in the page, try get messages without update messages component and find bug.